# Change tag value in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I have data being inserted that uses host names.  Annoyingly I'm about to change a domain from .lan to .mydomain.com

Obviously I'd like to be able to search my historical data of a machine as it crosses this change.

Can I update a tag definition from machine.lan to machine.mydomain.com?

Comment: Annoyingly, InfluxDB doesn't support some basic (to those coming from SQL) operations like [updating tags](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4157#issuecomment-354939104), [searching for NULLs](https://github.com/influxdata/docs.influxdata.com/issues/717), [updating fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070399/update-field-value-in-influxdb), [dropping fields](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6150), or operators like [IN](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/2157).

Answer (score 13):

While @Michael's answer is correct in that you can't change tag values via InfluxDB commands, you can however write a client script that can change the value of a tag by inserting ["duplicate"](/questions/39685114/delete-points-with-unwanted-field-values-from-influxdb-measurement/39694049#39694049) points in the measurement with the same timestamp, fieldset and tagset, except that the desired tag will have its value changed.

Point with wrong tag (in [Line Protocol](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/#syntax) format):

```
cpu,hostname=machine.lan cpu=50 1514970123
```

After running

```
INSERT cpu,hostname=machine.mydomain.com cpu=50 1514970123
```

a SELECT * FROM CPU would include

```
cpu,hostname=machine.lan cpu=50 1514970123
cpu,hostname=machine.mydomain.com cpu=50 1514970123
```

After the script runs all the INSERT commands, you'll need to drop the obsolete series of points with the old tag value:

```
DROP SERIES FROM cpu WHERE hostname='machine.lan'
```

Of course, this is highly inefficient (note in particular [this bug](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7826#issuecomment-355205713)) and if you need to update a tag value to [another tag value that other points you don't want to drop already have](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4157#issuecomment-354939104), you can't just `DROP SERIES`. So please [vote for InfluxDB to implement tag renaming](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4157) and in particular, changing tag values based on `WHERE` queries. Or consider an alternative time-series database that lets you use regular SQL, such as [Timescale](https://timescale.com).

Comment: Wow. This answers my question perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to change tag names for historical data in InfluxDB.

Comment: I looked at trying to copy data from one table to another, manually specifying the new tag name, but I didn't seem to be able to do that either.

Comment: You could query all of the data out, manually rename it, then rewrite it.

Comment: Dump it to csv?  Is that possible? And the import?

Comment: @dcole there's a tool called [influx_inspect](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/tools/influx_inspect/) that allows you to pull raw TSM files.

Answer (score 4):

> There is already an open feature request on GitHub for this.
>   https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4157

A probable solution suggested by influx developer if you want to go down the dump all, modify, re-import path (brutal, but effective), this comment might help.

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3904#issuecomment-268918613

Answer (score 0):

As other people have commented, the process seems to be:

1. Load all the points you wish to change to local memory.
2. Change all these points.
3. Upload them back to influx.
4. Delete the old values.

I wrote some helper functions in python today to do this for me, which I though I could share. The solution is a bit bulky, but I had most of the functions from before. I am sure there are other more concise ways, but I could not find a full python example, so here is mine:

Main function:

```
def replace_tag(database_name:str, measurement_name:str, tag:str, old_value:str, new_value:str,):
    """ Replaces an existing tag into a measurement, with a new tag for all affected records by deleting and reuploading """

    # Get a dataframe of selected data
    q = 'SELECT * FROM "'+ measurement_name + '"' + ' WHERE "' + tag + '" = ' + "'" + old_value + "'"
    df = influx_get_read_query(query=q, database_name=database_name)
    print(df)

    tags_keys = influx_get_tag_keys(database_name=database_name)
    field_keys = influx_get_field_keys(database_name=database_name, measurement_name=measurement_name)

    # Here we collect all the new records to be written to influx
    new_points = []

    # Loop through each row of the returned dataframe
    for i in trange(0, len(df)):
        row = df.iloc[i]
        print('row:', i)
        row_dict = row.to_dict()
        print('old row dict:', row_dict)

        new_tags = {}
        new_fields = {}
        new_time = ''

        for key in row_dict.keys():
            if key in tags_keys:
                new_tags[key] = row_dict[key]

            elif key in field_keys:
                new_fields[key] = row_dict[key]

            elif key == 'time':
                new_time = row_dict[key]

            else:
                easygui.msgbox('WARNING: A KEY WAS NOT FOUND: ' + str(key))

        # Replace the old value with a new value
        new_tags[tag] = new_value

        new_row_dict = {}
        new_row_dict['measurement'] = measurement_name
        new_row_dict['tags'] = new_tags
        new_row_dict['time'] = new_time
        new_row_dict['fields'] = new_fields


        # print('new row dict:', new_row_dict)
        new_points.append(new_row_dict)

    # Write the revised records back to the database
    influx_write_multiple_dicts(data_dicts=new_points, database_name=database_name)
    # When finished, delete all records.
    influx_delete_series(database_name=database_name, measurement_name=measurement_name, tag=tag, tag_value=old_value)
```

Other helper funnctions:

```
def influx_delete_series(database_name, measurement_name, tag, tag_value):

    q = 'DROP SERIES FROM "' + measurement_name + '"' + ' WHERE "' + tag + '" = ' + "'" + tag_value + "'"
    client = InfluxDBClient(host=HOST_ADDRESS, port=PORT, username="InfluxDB", password="Influx-DB-PASSWORD")
    client.switch_database(database_name)
    client.query(q, chunked=True, chunk_size=10000000000000000)


def influx_write_multiple_dicts(data_dicts:list, database_name):
    """Write a list of dicts with following structure:
    database_output_influx['measurement'] = 'SENSOR_ELEMENT_SUMMARY_TEST2'
        database_output_influx['tags'] = {'serialNumber':'1234', 'partNumber':'5678'}
        d = datetime.now()
        timestamp = d.isoformat('T')
        database_output_influx['time'] = timestamp
        database_output_influx['fields'] = summary_results_dict
    """
    client = InfluxDBClient(host=HOST_ADDRESS, port=PORT, username="InfluxDB", password="Influx-DB-PASSWORD")
    client.switch_database(database_name)
    print("Return code for influx write:", client.write_points(data_dicts))


def influx_get_tag_keys(database_name):

    client = InfluxDBClient(host=HOST_ADDRESS, port=PORT, username="InfluxDB", password="Influx-DB-PASSWORD")
    # client.create_database('SIEMENS_ENERGY_TEST')
    client.switch_database(database_name)

    results = client.query("SHOW TAG KEYS ")
    point_list = []
    points = results.get_points()
    for point in points:
        point_list.append(point['tagKey'])

    return point_list


def influx_get_field_keys(measurement_name, database_name):

    client = InfluxDBClient(host=HOST_ADDRESS, port=PORT, username="InfluxDB", password="Influx-DB-PASSWORD")
    client.switch_database(database_name)

    results = client.query("SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM " + measurement_name)
    point_list = []
    points = results.get_points()
    for point in points:
        point_list.append(point['fieldKey'])

    return point_list

def influx_get_read_query(query, database_name):
    """Returns a df of all measurements that have a certain field or value, for example stage. Note: single quotes for tag values, double quotes for al else. So best to use triple quotes surrounding statement. example:"""
    # q = """SELECT * FROM "SENSOR_ELEMENT_TEST_CYCLE" WHERE "TestStage" = '120'"""

    client = InfluxDBClient(host=HOST_ADDRESS, port=PORT, username="InfluxDB", password="Influx-DB-PASSWORD")
    client.switch_database(database_name)
    # print("Dataframe of all measurments of type:", measurement_name)
    q = query
    df = pd.DataFrame(client.query(q, chunked=True, chunk_size=10000000000000000).get_points())
    # print("DF: ", tabulate(df, headers=df.columns.tolist(), tablefmt="psql"))
    return df
```