# Update multiple field values matching a condition in InfluxDB

Tags: sql-update, influxdb

In an InfluxDB measurement, how can the field values of points matching a query be updated? Is this still [not easily doable as of v1.6](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/2575)?

As the example in that GitHub ticket suggested, what's the cleanest way of achieving something like this?

```
UPDATE access_log SET username='something' WHERE mac='xxx'
```

Anything better than driving it all from the client by [updating individual points](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-does-influxdb-handle-duplicate-points)?

Comment: just out of curiosity: what could be the need to update the past?

Comment: @YuriG: [classifying/categorizing data](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/influxdb/rL4lQRu5lv4), [updating outlier values (usually due to collection errors) that affect means](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3210), [delete unwanted field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685114/delete-points-with-unwanted-field-values-from-influxdb-measurement), [rename values to conform to a new naming scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990346/change-tag-value-in-influxdb) etc. Basically with Influx, you need to have a perfect schema + data format from the start.

Answer (score 8):

**Q:** How can the field values of points matching a query be updated? Is this still not easily doable as of v1.4?

**A:** From the best of my knowledge, there isn't an easy way to accomplish `update` in version `1.4` yet.

`Field value` of a point can only be updated by overriding. That is, to overwrite its value you'll need to know the details of your points. These details include its `timestamp` and `series` information, which is the measurement it reside and its corresponding `tags`.

**Note:** This "update" strategy can only be used for changing the `field` value but not `tag` value. To update a `tag` value you'll need to first `DELETE` the point data first and rewrite the entire point data with the updated tag and value.

**Q:** Anything better than driving it all from the client by updating individual points?

**A:** Influxdb supports [multi-point write](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/guides/writing_data/#writing-multiple-points). So if you can build a filter to pre-select a small dataset of points,  modify their  `field` values and then override them in bulk.

Answer (score 1):

Update is possible and would take the format:

INSERT measurement,tag_name=tag_value_no_quotes value_key_1=value_value_1,value_key_2=value_value_2 time

for example where I want to update the line with tag my_box at time 1526988768877018669 on the box measurement:

INSERT box,box_name=my_box item_1='apple',item_2='melon' 1526988768877018669

Comment: Isn't this [updating an individual point form the client](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-does-influxdb-handle-duplicate-points)? As I had specified in the question, I'm looking for updating multiple field values rather than individual points one by one. Anyway, I've updated the question to make that even clearer.